# Why does consuming a RESTful web service (using javax.ws.rs.* and Jsersey) work in unit test but not when submitted to Spark?

Tags: unit-testing, rest, jax-rs, apache-spark, jersey-2.0

I have a piece of code that runs inside Spark Streaming and tries to get some data from a RESTful web service. The code snippet in question is:

```
 Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
 WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:2222/rest");
 target = target.path("annotate")
             .queryParam("text", UrlEscapers.urlFragmentEscaper().escape(spotlightSubmission))
             .queryParam("confidence", "0.3");

 logger.warn("!!! DEBUG !!! target: {}", target.getUri().toString());

 String response = target.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get(String.class);

 logger.warn("!!! DEBUG !!! Spotlight response: {}", response);
```

When run inside a unit test as follows:

```
 mvn clean test -Dtest=SpotlightTest#testCountWords
```

it contacts the RESTful web service and retrieves some data as expected. But when the same code is run as part of the application that is submitted to Spark, using `spark-submit` script, I receive the following error:

```
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap.addAll(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

as soon as it tries to run:

```
String response = target.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get(String.class);
```

I'm using **Spark 1.1.0** and for consuming the web service I'm using **Jersey** in my project's pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.14</version>
</dependency>
```

So I suspect that when the application is submitted to Spark, somehow there's a different JAR in the environment that uses a different version of Jersey / javax.ws.rs.*

Does anybody know which version of Jersey / javax.ws.rs.*  is used in the Spark environment, or how to solve this conflict?

Comment: I'm not a Spark user, but just doing a quick search, it appears the [yarn module depends on 1.9](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/yarn/pom.xml).

Comment: Indeed, that seems to be the case! I've modified my pom.xml to include Jersey 1.9.1 and also modified my code to use the older Jersey API. Now it seems to run (though this time Spark complains about not enough memory when running the same code in unit test, but that seems to be separate issue). If you write  your comment as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer: I'm not a Spark user**

But doing a quick search I found the [**yarn module depends on Jersey 1.9**](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/yarn/pom.xml).